# unable to create jtable in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jtable

hi i wanted to create a jtable in jsp and after a lots of google search i found this site as this site says i will have a default table but when i run it i get a blank page.please help me
http://jtable.org/GettingStarted#ListAction

```
   <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
<link href="/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<script src="/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
                createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
                updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
                deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
            },
            fields: {
                PersonId: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Author Name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                Age: {
                    title: 'Age',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                RecordDate: {
                    title: 'Record date',
                    width: '30%',
                    type: 'date',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your page have access to the jquery.jtable.min.js ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained yes, see i have test folder.inside test folder index.html and jtable folder. inside jtable i have jquery.jtable.min.js

Comment: Do you get any error in debugger console of Firebug or Chrome ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained no,i just get a blank page

Comment: Did you include jquery library ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained do you mean jquery-1.9.1.min.js? if yes then i have included it

Comment: Try to open the console in Firebug or Chrome and check for errors and also keep an eye on the network tab to see if all the libraries are accessible !!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained i thought that js files are not loading so after running the file in the browser,i clicked on the view source and then i clicked the necessary js files. when i am clicking on the links(js links) then it is displaying the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://raw.github.com/akashshinde/project/master/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/akashshinde/project/raw/master/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->

<link href="https://raw.github.com/akashshinde/project/master/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://raw.github.com/akashshinde/project/master/scripts/jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<script src="https://raw.github.com/akashshinde/project/master/scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Table of people',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
            createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
            updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
            deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
        },
        fields: {
            PersonId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Author Name',
                width: '40%'
            },
            Age: {
                title: 'Age',
                width: '20%'
            },
            RecordDate: {
                title: 'Record date',
                width: '30%',
                type: 'date',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually javascript files are not loading correctly in your jsp file
so navigate .js files correctly in url,as I entered it in above code.

```
Just replace code with your code
```

Comment: Can you explain what did you do different so that the Op can understand the concept and merely don't copy the code !!!

Comment: @akash shinde same blank page

Comment: @NoobUnChained , i just referring sample example given by author of jTable

Comment: @javaL , As jTable uses ajax ,so you need to load ajax request from javascript therefor i added code to load the Ajax Request to div->PersonTableContainer

Comment: @javaL,can you give us your project folder link so that i can test it

Comment: @AkashShinde well as per the author(the link in my question) when you just create the <div id="PersonTableContainer"></div> then it will show age,name and add new record headings. but i am not getting any headings,just only a blank page.thats why i have asked whether you have tested the code that you have posted or not

Comment: @javaL,its working for me now , i tested it ! will add it in answer

Comment: @AkashShinde sorry to say this is also not working for me,can you give me your email id so that i will send the project

Comment: okk,i am editing answer code again to get .js files directly from internet,so there will no problem with js loading from local storage ..! :)

Comment: @AkashShinde thanks for the answer,it was not working as desired but it is acceptable. well i am implementing this idea in jsp. insertion/deletion etc need to be done in jsp. so please tell me when you click on the add new record then it will display a form to enter and when you hit submit then it is linking to some where.please tell me to where it is linking. th jtable code is in .net and i am totally unaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're not include [jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) library, try to put this before your `jtable` link:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @Nooob Unchained please see my edited question,i have included that

Comment: @javaL you need to put your referenced jQuery library before your referenced jtable script

Comment: sorry for the previous post,i have done as you said but still not getting the desired output.i am only getting blank page. Do you know any other open source jquery jtable which i can use.thanks in advance

Comment: i have to do an appointment page in which it will take name,start time,end time etc. so the site you suggested does not have a option to enter new records. The link in my post is best suitable for my requirement because it have an option to add new entry and when you click it will reflect in the same page.